# Open a new window Onclick of image button

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.5, the latest release for our development work!
Inside the prime face datatable , i have commandLink which is used to open a new window , based on the URL constructed with the request parameter.Attached the code for reference.

```
<p:dataTable>
<p:column style="text-align:center;">
<h:commandLink value="" action="#{claimStatusBean.npfInfo.handleNpf }" target="_blank" >
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="star_small.png" rendered="#{claimStatus.npfProvider}"/>
</h:commandLink>    
</p:column>
<p:dataTable>
```

But when i click the action is never invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `h:commandLink` to `p:commandLink` and set the `process` attribute to `@this` or another component surrounding your datatable such as the form id.

For example:

```
<p:commandLink value="" process="@this" action="#{claimStatusBean.npfInfo.handleNpf }" target="_blank" >
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="star_small.png" rendered="#{claimStatus.npfProvider}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: Thanks For the Response ! I tried this option , Its not opening the URL which i have constructed in the backin bean , it throwing the exception.

Comment: @user1669692 So you are saying that in the method `claimStatusBean.npfInfo.handleNpf` you are returning `return "http://someurl.com";` but it's not opening the address?  Is it a JSF page or a url on another domain? You may need to redirect instead of returning a String which JSF will try to handle.

Comment: Yes , It's opening the url in same window not in the another window.